# NestedScroll View flikkers when scroll change

Tags: java, android

Hey i have implemented scrollView.setOnScrollChangeListner() to my nested scroll view.
then i tried to hide/show my action bar when user scrolls . but the my screen flikers when I scroll.

I think the reason behind it is when the user is scrolling the view  at  every instance of time OnScroll() invoked which may leads to flikring (it may be possible my actionBar is showing/hiding so fast that it seems to me flickring)

Thanks in Advance

'''

```
scrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new View.OnScrollChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScrollChange(View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {

                    if (scrollY > oldScrollY){
                        if (searchActive){
                            searchBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }else {
                            actionBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }else if (scrollY < oldScrollY){
                        if (searchActive){
                            searchBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }else {
                            actionBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

'''

Comment: Seems like you answered your own question in the question itself?

Comment: But how to solve it?

Comment: Use an animation to slow down the effect and your logic may be wrong, why the view is gone for both if and else? and parent if else both condition visible. Learn more, you will come up with better solutions.

Comment: Thanks, i will try

Comment: No my logic is not wrong. I have done that for some special pupose that i can't explain here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi friend scrollview on callback px
you convert px to dp in android
size toolbar or actionbar 56dp

```
functions kotlin convert
  fun Convert_px(px: Float,context:Context):Int{
        val resources=context.resources
        val metrics=resources.displayMetrics
        val dp=px / (metrics.densityDpi.toFloat() / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT)
        return dp.toInt()
    }
```

scrollview

```
binding?.scrollView?.viewTreeObserver?.addOnScrollChangedListener{
                var scroll_number:Int? = binding?.scrollView?.scrollY
                val dpsize : Int?=Convert_px(scroll_number!!.toFloat(),this@MainActivity)
                if(dpsize!! > 56){
                     searchBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
               else{
 searchBar.setVisibility(View.show);
               }

            }
```

or matril destion coord

CoordinatorLayout